# Use boost::function as function argument?

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

I want to call a function foo and let it behave differently.
(I'm adopting Strategy or Command pattern. They look similar to me.)

My overall plan is as follows..

First, define foo to take boost::function type

> ```
> foo(boost::function<someType> execFunction)
> {
> // do something 
> execFunction(args);
> // do something
> }
> ```

Then, I give foo() different functions(as argument) depending on what I want.

Would this work? or Would you advise against it?
Any comments are welcome.

### edit

Minor related question is,
sometimes execFunction needs 1 argument, and other times it needs 2 arguments.

I could use boost::function for both cases and just ignore the 2nd argument when not needed.
Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Difficult to provide advice - it's not really clear what you want to do. Outwardly, the approach is fine - if not very scalable (as in for each function you'll have to overload, you could work around that by making this a template), then you'd have to question the need for `boost::function` wrapper...

Comment: That's what boost::function is for, so of course it's okay to use it like that, generally speaking. The real question should be, is this appropriate for your particular case, which cannot be answered because you didn't provide any information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works very well. But sometimes it is preferable to work with a
functor so your callers are free to choose what is best for them and to prevent the smalll overhead that comes with a `boost::function`:

```
template<typename Func>
void foo(Func f) {
  f(myArgs);
}
```

You can also add an overload for the specific `boost::function` to take the object by reference.

```
template<>
void foo(const boost::function<void (expectedtypes)>& f) {
  f(myArgs);
}
```

And possibly have that overloaded for constness as well.

For the case of accepting `boost::function` objects of different arity, I'd use overloading. If you go that route, avoid the templated version as you are going to run into trouble as soon as your users try to work with functors (as opposed to `boost::function` with different arity). This trouble is resolvable, but can get messy. You would need to dispatch the call to something that detects the arity of the funtor and executes the proper call. But as you said that templates are your weak-point, this isn't really recommended.

Comment: You seem to imply that `template<typename Func> void foo(const Func& f)` would somehow cause trouble. If so, how?

Comment: @sehe I prefer passing functors by value as this is the policy set by the stdlib for various reasons. I can look for a summary of the argument to make my point complete if you like or we could have a new question about this. Comments just suck for this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

That is a common pattern, and will work. I have used that in the past and will most probably use it in the future. I try to use it only in some specific use cases, as it reduces drastically coupling, and while that is good in general, it makes it harder to follow the flow of control from the code (i.e. if you abuse it, it will be really hard to find what your program is meant to do other than running it in the debugger). But for specific tasks it is fine.

If you do not need to store the `function<>` for later use, or any runtime polymorphic behavior on the callee side, you can also consider using a function template, so that callers don't need to convert to `function<>` before executing your function.

Comment: David: Comforting to hear it will work. I just read boost::function boost::bind related doc today for the first time, can you elaborate on your 2nd paragraph? (possibly with a sample code) Template is my weak point as well.

Comment: @Eugene: Basically that you can just do `template <typename Functor> void f( Functor execF ) { execF(args); }`, and that will enable different uses that don't require going through the extra *type-erasure* step of `function<>`, unless, of course you need the *type-erasure* for example because you want to store the functor to execute later, or this is a virtual function that cannot be templated.